# What exactly does "cloud computing" mean?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, cloud, cloud-hosting, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to cloud field, i want to know what it is from basic?

What are its advantages?
How it comes to use in real life?
Comparison with the existing technologies.

Comment: Looks like this should have the homework tag.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud computing isn't a technology, it's a concept.
It means all your data (documents, photo's, music and even applications) is stored on a central server ('the cloud'). The advantage of this is that you can access your personal stuff from all your devices. If you want to listen to your music from a computer or some other device: no problem, since it's all 'in the cloud'.